# matlab output from function

Tags: matlab, function

I am doing some matlab work and I am stuck on this function and can't find what's wrong.

That is my function

```
function [e] = Ek(fk,m,n)
for i=8:m-7
    for j=8:n-7 
        e(i,j)=some code here;
end 
end
```

I am calling that function from an other file with this command

```
bla= Ek(array, m, n);
```

The error I am getting is

Error in Ek (line 2)
    for i=8:m-7

Output argument "e" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"some path/Ek.m>Ek".

Comment: Could it be, that you called your function with `m` or `n` being smaller than 15? It'd be cleaner to actually initialize e prior to your `for`-loops.

Comment: Oh yeah they had the value of 5 right before the function was called!

Answer (score 1):

You should be pre-allocating e, for example

```
function [e] = Ek(fk,m,n)

e=zeros(m,n);   %pre-allocate

for i=8:m-7
    for j=8:n-7 
        e(i,j)=some code here;
end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to check the values of the parameters `m` and `n` before the loop. They might be less than 15.